# Do I need to let my basement subfloor breathe?

Tags: basement, flooring, moisture

I live in a mostly cold environment and I’m planning to finish my basement floor with standard interlocking foam tiles (with a slight rigid texture) for underlayment (soft/insulated) topped with roll-down adhesive vinyl planks.

I’ve read things about letting the floor breathe, and other people saying to lay down plastic, and others not even mentioning it.

The foam underlayment is .5” thick and interlocking, so I don’t imagine much moisture working through it. Ceilings are 7’, so I’m hoping to keep everything under 1””. If I had the money, I would buy the fancy bubbled foam underlayment, but my current solution has me under $2/sq’. = AFFORDABLE.

Is my current solution sufficient, or should I avoid/take extra steps?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question; let's see if one of our pros has an answer for you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Mostly cold is relative. Where are you located, city & state? How dry is your basement? Is it dirt or concrete? Do you ever get damp floors, musty smells, damp air? Do you have a radon system, air conditioning, or anything to draw out humid air? Foam is a big sponge. If there's any moisture, foam will trap and hold it, contributing to mold & mildew. When we know more particulars we can give better answers.

Comment: Hi Eric, I live in Sheboygan, WI. Fairly humid and short summers in 80’s. 

Concrete floors, dehumidifier runs about half the day. We didn’t used a dehumidifier last summer and eventually got mold/mildew buildup. 

A/c upstairs, nothing in basement as it stays cold all year and hardly runs enough to keep basement air dry. No radon system. No sump. No flooding issues- soil is almost 100% sand around home. Roof overhangs foundation by at least 3’ and positive drainage, good gutters. 

Foam flooring is balancefrom‘s EVA foam interlocking floor tiles for gyms, play areas, etc.